# Synonym requests for "google-plus-hangouts"

Tags: support, synonym-request, retag-request

The official name is [Google+ Hangouts](http://www.google.com/hangouts/).

Please rename [google-plus-hangout](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-hangout) to [google-plus-hangouts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-hangouts).

Then, please synonymize and merge [google-hangouts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) to [google-plus-hangouts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-hangouts).

Also, the original "Huddles" was re-branded Google+ Messenger, but that latter has been consolidated into Hangouts as well. Therefore, please synonymize and merge [google-plus-huddles](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-huddles) to [google-plus-hangouts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-hangouts).

Comment: Do we need to worry about Huddles? It was just an internal code-name, it was renamed to Hangouts before it was released, wasn't it? Plus we don't seem to have any questions tagged with that at the moment, so it should die pretty soon...

Comment: I see three questions tagged with [tag:google-plus-huddles]. Maybe we don't need to fix it. Since they can't be answered they should probably be closed.

Comment: Well that's odd, so do I now, but there were none showing when I clicked the tag link just now?

Comment: The first two parts are done. Looking into the third a bit...